# TV tuner streams low quality TV video

Tags: television, quality

I've bought [EyeTV Hybrid from Elgato](http://www.elgato.com/elgato/na/mainmenu/products/EyeTV-Hybrid-10/product1.en.html), an USB TV tuner to watch television on mac.
I've plugged to the USB stick my tv antenna cable (free air-broadcasted analog television).

It works, but the image is a bit pixelated, not very good quality, like in the normal TV.

I've tried to unplug/plug cables and the USB stick, restart the mac,  but it is the same.
In the settings I can see the strength of the signal is 100% and its' quality is between 90 and 95%.

I've also tried all things they mention here:
http://support.elgato.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=3046

I don't get why I can't get the same quality I get on my normal TV.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the EyeTV software? This is only a guess, but if you're still using VLC it might have something to do with that.

Comment: No, I never used VLC. That was another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely use the EyeTV software. Now for the signal - over the air broadcast are great, but you have to triangulate the signal. So, if the nearest tower is on the opposite side of the building you're in, then the signal has to pass through the building before it gets to your antennae. I would look up the nearest tower on the web, get your Hybrid as close to that direction as you can, and/or add an actual antennae to the Hybrid - the device by itself is basically just a converter/tuner. I've also been able to plug in a cable or sat coax to it and gotten even better results. I'm still tweaking that setup.

Comment: I'm using the EyeTV software of course. Why do you suppose I'm not using it ?

Comment: I wrote in the question that I'm using the antenna cable, so there is no antenna to orientate.